# Overcoming the 2GB limit with VBA

Tags: vba

Is there a way to overcome the 2GB limit of files in VBA ? Before trying to use multiple files controlling them by my own code, I would like to ask for any hints on the topic.

Comment: *Which* files do you think have this limit in VBA?  Stream reading and writing a text file should not have this limit.  Source files and memory-mapped files definitely do though.

Comment: Using "Random" files with Get/Put and "Sequential" with Input/Print. With both of them the barrier is 2,147,483,647 which is actually the size of a Long type number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [file system object model (FSO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa711216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead.  Specifically, the [OpenTextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265341%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) method of the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242698%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) object.  I cannot find anything that explicitly says that it can go over 2GB, but lot of places imply it.  If you use the `ReadLine` method of `TextStream` and all of the lines are under 2GB, it should work.

On the other hand, VBA does have some memory limitations also, so you want to make sure to *stream* this: don't try to keep all of the lines in memory at once, just one or two at a time.

Comment: I can confirm that the file can go over the 2GB limit. I have just tested with 24,000,000 of 218 chars in length and ASCII output which results in 5,232,000,000. BUT, I was not able to ADD records in the existing file and also no CR/LF exist at the end of each record. Are the above normal ?

Comment: There is a small bug in the code supplied by Microsoft in the OpenTextStream page. When it says ForAppending = 3, it should be ForAppending = 8.

Comment: After some reading in MSDN articles and some testing, I think that you have given me a very good hint in order to solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I was going forward with your suggestion, with files well over the 2GB limit, I discovered that fso.Skip (numofchars) has this 2GB limit. You can not specify a number of chars greater than 2GB. A workaround is to do repeated skips with smaller than 2GB values.