# VBA Error: run time error 2046 the command or action quit isn't available now

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following piece of VBA code has been working for more than a year.

I am running Microsoft Access 2013

```
Public Function AutoUpdate()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    'AutoCrawle 'a function that does the expected task.
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Application.Quit
End Function
```

Lately it throws the following error:

> run time error 2046 the command or action 'quit' isn't available now.

It is generated from the line: `Application.Quit`

Any Ideas why this happens? Over time, the file has grown large up two 2Gigabytes, due to growth of a record set.

**EDIT**: Also without AutoCrawle function same scenario happens. So I commented it.

Comment: The file size limit is 2GB so you could possibly be reaching that limit with temporary tables etc. depending on what your function does. Whether that would cause the hang or would actually error I don't know. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870721/overcoming-the-2gb-limit-with-vba) may be of help.

Comment: aah, good point. I also notice now that the file won't grow anymore and only a second file is created and is growing. This must mean that Access is taking care of all of its storage affairs. I just shrank the file to 10MB and retried, same error. Maybe the cause of error is that I have the UI open, while I am debugging, and this part of code is supposed to be triggered via task scheduler... So not possible to quit while UI is open... what do you think?

Comment: Without seeing what the function is doing it is very difficult to speculate, Have you tried `DoEvents` before trying to quit? It could be a trust/permissions problem, does it quit successfully if you don't execute `AutoCrawle`?

Comment: actually no. without that function it gives the same result.

Comment: In that case, is it in a [trusted location](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4)?

Comment: At one trigger event does this function run? And why are you quitting the Access application? Do you want to exit database?

Comment: @JBES it is not in a trusted location, and moving it to a trusted location also didn't help.

Comment: @Parfait user command via GUI triggers this for debugging. Overall it is triggered by Task scheduler as a shell command, and In that case it is O.K. I need to quit the APPLICATION. since it is a regularly scheduled task.

Comment: Are there open forms that are not being closed before the quit command?